# AWS CDK pass CfnCodeRepository to CfnModel

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm deploying model and endpoint via CDK in python.
Deployment of the model requires to provide python script as entry point. Currently this script is packed together with the model into tar.gz file on S3.CfnModelreferences this S3 location.

The question is, can I use CfnCodeRepository to pass code to CfnModel instead of packing it together with my model?

As of now I was successful to configure git repo only while training within sagemaker notebook.

This is the code example:

```
        sklearn_container = aws_sagemaker.CfnModel.ContainerDefinitionProperty(
            image=skl_image,
            image_config=aws_sagemaker.CfnModel.ImageConfigProperty(repository_access_mode="Platform"),
            container_hostname="SklearnContainer",
            model_data_url=LINK TO MODEL TAR.GZ ON S3,
            environment={
                'SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL': 10,
                'SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY': sklearn_model_artifacts,
                'SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM': 'clf_inference.py', -> SCRIPT PACKED WITH MODEL WITHIN TAR.GZ
                'SAGEMAKER_REGION': region
            }
        )

        containers = [sklearn_container]

        role = XXX

        multi_model = aws_sagemaker.CfnModel(
            self,
            id="SOME-MODEL-ID",
            execution_role_arn=role.role_arn,
            model_name='SOME-MODEL-NAME',
            containers=containers)
```

Comment: Please add a minimal CDK code example.

Comment: @fedonev, added to the description. the idea is to replace clf_inference.py on git repo.